# Java public static main()

Tags: java

I am learning Java, theres one thing I do not understand..

in the main routine:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

I think I pretty much understand this, in the language I know, I think it would be like this:

```
public static function main(args:String):void {
```

The first thing I do not understand is what are the 2 brackets [] for in String[]? Also the second thing I am wondering, is if this is the first function that will be called (and called by something outside the program), will there ever actually be a parameter passed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The arguments to main are the options you pass into Java from the command line, passed in as an array.  So for example :

```
java MyProgram foo bar zoo
```

takes three arguments, namely, foo, bar, and zoo

foo is args[0], bar is args[1], and zoo is args[2].

Comment: Thanks this answers my question but raises 1 more I am wondering if anyone can answer for me. If you can define arrays like String[] and int[] or whatever, is there still a formal array class? which could hold different types of data...I am assuming you only define an array this way when you want to specify it only can contain that particular data type? Thanks.

Comment: You can use collections and vectors for that

Comment: @John Isaacks "is there still a formal array class? which could hold different types of data": Well an Object[] will hold all types of references (because all reference types are subtypes of Object). Reference types and primitive types are separate in Java, so there is no supertype for all types, but primitive types can be boxed into reference types.

Answer (score 5):

Brackets mean [array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_type). E.g. `String[]` is an array of strings. The `main()`-function is the first function called in your program. It gets called by the [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JVM).

The values in `String[] args` are the parameters passed on the command line.

If you call a Java program (main class: `FooBar` in package `foo.bar`) like that:

```
java foo.bar.FooBar foo bar buz
```

then, `args` will like if you built it like that:

```
String[] args = new String[3];
args[0] = "foo";
args[1] = "bar";
args[2] = "buz";
```

That is possibly worth reading: [A Closer Look at the "Hello World" Application](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

The brackets mean that it's an array of Strings. And there can be parameters, e.g. from the command line when your start your application.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you'll get an array of strings. They may be passed via command line

Answer (score 0):

[] stands for array for example
String x = "some value";
String[] x = {"value 1","value 2","value 3"};

so in second case x[0] gives "value 1". It is basically an array of strings.
Second part is who will call the function? Well this method signature is entry signature and whenever you try to invoke a class with java program, it'll search for this function to start execution; if it doesn;t find it; it'll just give out an error.

Who will pass the vales to String[] array? 
java someprogram value1 value2 value3

will automatically populate the array with respective three values. So basically the values are populated when it is run from command prompt and values are passed as parameters against the call.

Hope that clears it up